# Join on foreign key in Kafka stream

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Lets say that I have three Kafka topics filled with events representing business events occuring in different aggregates (event sourcing application). These events allow to build aggregates with following attributes :

- users : usedId, name
- modules of an application : moduleId, name
- grants of users for modules of application : grantId, userId, moduleId, scope

Now I want to create a stream of all grants with name of users and products (instead of id).
I thought to do so :

1. create a KTable for users by grouping events by userId. The KTable has userId as key. It is ok.
2. create a KTable for products by grouping events by productId. The KTable has productId as key. It is ok.
3. create a stream from the stream of Grants and joining on the two KTable.
   It is no ok. The problem is that joins seem only possible on primary keys. But the key of the stream is an technical identifier of the Grant and keys of users and products tables are not (they are agnostic of Grant).

So how to proceed ?

Comment: Is product table same as module table?

Comment: No they are two different tables. But they are used in the same way in this case (just as reference table to get information of users and of modules).

Comment: So which key do you want to use in Grants table to refer the product ID?

Comment: In Grants stream I want to use the `userId` field to join to the Users table, and the `moduleId` field to join to the Modules table. The key of Grants stream is `grantId`.

Comment: please check the answer, and see if it helps you

Comment: This use case is usually referred to as something like "Enriching a stream of events by information from one or multiple tables", which is achieved by a KTable-KStream join as described in the answer below. There is also an example in the great kafka-streams-examples repository: https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples/blob/5.4.1-post/src/main/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/PageViewRegionLambdaExample.java

Answer (score 10):

Well, there is no direct support for Foreign key join at the moment in Kafka Streams.
There is an open KIP : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-3705 for the same.

For now, there can be a workaround to solve this problem. You can use **KStream-KTable Join**.

First Aggregate the **User** Stream and **Module** Stream into respective KTable with aggregated collection of Events.

```
KTable<String,Object> UserTable = userStream.groupBy(<UserId>).aggregate(<... build collection/latest event>) ;
KTable<String,Object> ModuleTable = moduleStream.groupBy(<ModuleId>).aggregate(<... build collection/latest event>);
```

Now select the moduleID as a key in the **Grants** stream.

```
KStream<String,Object> grantRekeyedStream = grantStream.selectKey(<moduleId>);
```

It will change the key to **moduleId**. Now you can perform Stream-Table Join with **ModuleTable**. It will join all the matching records from right side for the key in the left side. Result stream will have **Grant** and **Module** data into one stream with **ModuleId** as key.

```
KStream<String,Object> grantModuleStream = grantRekeyedStream.join(moduleTable);
```

Next step is to join with **userTable**. Hence you need to rekey the **grantModuleTable** again with **userId**.

```
KStream<String,Object> grantModuleRekeyedStream = grantModuleTable.selectKey(<Select UserId>);
```

Now **grantModuleRekeyedStream** can be joined with **userTable** with **KStream-KTable Join**

```
 KStream<String,Object> grantModuleUserStream = grantModuleRekeyedStream .join(userTable);
```

Above Stream will have user ID as a key and contain all grants and module details for that user.

Comment: @gentiane : If the answer solves your issue, please accept/upvote to help others

Comment: Great answer. The link you provided is about KTable-KTable non-key joins though. It has been implemented and released in the meantime. But it does not help in this scenario where two KStream-Ktable joins are used.

Answer (score 4):

This feature was [released](https://downloads.apache.org/kafka/2.4.0/RELEASE_NOTES.html) as part of Kafka Streams 2.4.0.

Here's an [official tutorial](https://kafka-tutorials.confluent.io/foreign-key-joins/kstreams.html) on using this feature.